# map to form select Scala Play2 using reactivemongo

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have in a Play2 Template:

```
files: Option[List[(String, reactivemongo.api.gridfs.ReadFile[reactivemongo.bson.BSONValue])]]
```

I would like to display the files in a drop down form Select, but only if the files are there!

How would I do this?

Comment: In priority, transform this very complex object in your controller (separation of concerns) to meet your needs

Comment: And remove the `Option` around the `List`, an `Option` is essentially a List of 0 or 1 elements.

Answer (score 0):

As Julien Lafont said, you should consider transforming this list before giving it to your template. For example if you just want a list of read files (on which you can call `filename` and `id`):

```
val fileList = files.toList.flatten.map(_._2) // fileList is a List[ReadFile[BSONValue]]]
```

And if you want just want to get filenames and their ids (given that their ids are `BSONObjectID`s), you may write this:

```
val fileList = files.toList.flatten.map { file =>
  val id = file._2.id match {
    case oid: BSONObjectID => oid.stringify
    case id => id.toString
  }
  id -> file._2.filename
}
// fileList is a List[(String, String)] where the first element of the tuple is a string version of the id and the second is the name of the file.
```

Comment: filesWithId.toList.flatten.map(_._1) does not work says cannot resolve symbol ._1 BUT val newid = filesWithId.toList.map(_._1) does